# mongodb query not utilising index with $expr

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

I have an index on the createdAt date field.

I have an aggregation with this $match stage as the first stage:

```
{   
    "$expr" : {
        "$gte" : [
            "$createdAt",
            {
                "$dateSubtract" : {
                    "startDate" : "$$NOW",
                    "unit" : "week",
                    "amount" : 2
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This query does not use an index when I look at the query plan. If I hardcode a date into the query it uses the index (e.g.  `"createdAt": { $gte: ISODate("2023-12-25") }`).

If I give an index hint, it correctly uses the index. Am I doing something wrong? Is the query planner selecting a colscan because at this point in time it is quicker than using an index? I am concerned that when i release this query to production, performance will be drop as it wont use an index.

Can someone explain why the index is not being used unless i specifically give an index hint?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) is not 100% clear, it only states:

> The `$eq`, `$lt`, `$lte`, `$gt`, and `$gte` comparison operators placed in an `$expr` operator can use an index on the `from` collection referenced in a `$lookup` stage.

I would assume, if the index is used within a `$lookup` stage, then MongoDB should be also able to use an index in `$match` stage.

I think it is better to use the index hint.